# Onsen ui and Android text-input

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a problem with the input text on Android (version 4.0.4 .It will be work from version 4).
When I select the input field I cannot see what I'm writing because another field appear over there.

Simple code:

```
<ons-page id="login" >
<div class="login-form sfondo-bianco">

    <input id="id_txt" type="text" class="text-input text-input--underbar" placeholder="ID" value="">
    <input id="psw_txt" type="password" class="text-input text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" value="">
    <br><br>
    <ons-button id="login_btn" modifier="large" class="login-button" onclick="onLogin()">LOGIN</ons-button>
    <br>
    <ons-button modifier="quiet" class="forgot-password" onclick="myNav.pushPage('recupero.html')">Password dimenticata? <span>Clicca qui</span></ons-button>
    <ons-button modifier="quiet" class="forgot-password" onclick="myNav.pushPage('registrazione.html')">Non sei ancora iscritto? <span>Registrati</span></ons-button>
</div>
</ons-page>
```

Someone know this issue and can help me?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: the result is the same even if you try to deploy as a Cordova app?

Comment: @AndiPavllo yes is the same :(

Comment: that's very weird, it never happened to me, which version of android are you using? Please, provide also more code

Comment: @AndiPavllo I have added the Android version for my test and all the code  of my page (not more different from the other code). I have also other pages with the some behaviour.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I notice that if I change the height of the class .text-input in the css, then I can see the field. For example, if I set the height to 70px. It isn't really a solution because still remain the border around the selected field. What do you think about @AndiPavllo?